# Implement C++ program that allows user to run multiple processes (up to three at the same time) at the background

Tags: c++, linux, process, multiprocessing

I am new to Linux. The following are my codes. It's a little bit complicated for me to do the task so I wish there is someone who can give me hints. I appreciate your help.

*Caution: myself is also mess up with my code. So it is bad and unfinished but I really cannot continue without any direction.

I am trying to implement a C/C++ program called BP that allows user to run multiple processes (up to three at the same time) at the background. When three processes are currently running, further execution request will be pended (the process state is changed to “stopped”) and wait until another process is stopped
or terminated. While processes are running at the background, the user can input command to display information of the background processes, stop or kill a background process.

If users' input = 
bg [name of executable file] [a list of arguments]
Action: BP runs the executable file with a list of arguments at the background and continues to accept input from the user. If there are already 3 running processes, the process is stopped.;

bgkill --> kill the pid by user input

My problem is I don't know how to check the status of the processes to make sure there cannot be more than three background processes.
**[FlowChart](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rYa-kRBOzGrZj4I7Mu3JByQvhCIZPNLb/view?usp=sharing)** is here.

/.....skipped.../
   //The problem starts here with the bg and bgKill

```
void bg(string input) {
    // Using waitpid() to check child already finished before
    int notRunning = waitpid(bpid, NULL, WNOHANG);
    if (notRunning) status = 0;

    // Check status
    if (status > 3) {
        cout << "Stopped. " << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Check name is null or not
    if (input == "" || input.length() == 0) {
        cout << "BP: > Error: Name is null. " << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Fork a child process
    bpid = fork();
    if (bpid < 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    else if (bpid > 0) {
        // Parent Code
        cout << "BP: > Background process started with pid " << bpid << endl;
        status += 1;
    } else if (bpid == 0) {
        // Child Code

        // Parse command into array
        // Init Array
        int size = countArg(input);
        char *arg[size + 1];

        // Put substring into array
        string delimiter = " ";
        for (int argCount = 0; argCount < size; argCount++) {
            int pos = input.find(delimiter);
            arg[argCount] = strdup(input.substr(0, pos).c_str());
            input.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        }
        arg[size] = NULL;

        // Execute the command
        if (execvp(arg[0], arg) == -1) {
            // If execute failed
            if (fileExist(arg[0])) {
                cout << "execvp() is failed. Do you mean ./" << arg[0] << "?" << endl;
            } else cout << "execvp() is failed." << endl;
        }
    }
}

void bgKill(string pidStr) {
    // Check status
    if (status == 0) {
        cout << "BP: > No background process to kill." << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Check the pid is the background pid
    int pid = atoi(pidStr.c_str());
    if (pid == 0 || pid != bpid) return invalidProcess(pid);

    // Kill the process
    kill(pid, SIGTERM);
    cout << "BP: > Background process with pid " << pid << " was killed." << endl;

    // Reset all flag
    status = 0;
    bpid = 0;
}
```

Comment: I would be really thankful if someone can help

Comment: necessary information/context should be in the question, not behind links. And what is your question?

Comment: Too much code. Please post a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Dear all, edited thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three options:

- Block on `waitpid`. This is not *directly* an option, as you need to respond to input in the meantime, but you can do one of the following:

  - block in a child process and communicate changes back using a pipe or eventfd,
  - block in a separate thread and communicate changes back using a pipe, eventfd or shared memory

  You should then also adjust your main input loop to use `select`, such that you can respond to changes on either STDIN or the child process/thread.
- Poll `waitpid` as you do now. This is similar to the previous approach: rewrite your main input loop to `select` on STDIN for a few hundred milliseconds, then poll with `waitpid` if something has changed.
- Finally, you can register a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`. This function will be invoked whenever a child process is stopped or terminated, so you can respond to it (by eg starting one of the pending processes or setting a flag) and going back to blocking on input.